# Chartkick cannot render API in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, chartkick

I'm trying to make a line chart from the API data

`[{"Apr 11":{"count":150}},{"Apr 12":{"count":140}},{"Apr 13":{"count":160}}]`

I tried doing:

`@metrics.each do |data|
  data.each do |key, value|
    render json: data(:key).count
  end
end`

All example in chartkick is rendering Model data. I'm struggling with rendering API data. Can anyone explain me how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First build a json then return this one

```
json_object = @metrics.map do |m|
{ date_value  => { :count => count_value} }
end

render :json => json_object
```